# How can people draw over java applets and still have full functionality?

Tags: java, graphics, applet

I have tried multiple times to do this but they all fail.  For example, the game RuneScape is a popular web game which uses an applet.  There are botters which are able to draw over the applets and such, how do they do this?

This is an example of the text/image over the applet itself

[image]

Comment: *"There are botters.."* What is a 'botter'?

Comment: Note that it is relatively trivial for the code in an applet (or application) that does custom painting to draw a semi-transparent rectangle over a portion of the rendering and write text on top.  If not doing custom rendering, there is always the glass pane for the same effect.

Comment: A botter is a person who doesn't play the game legit, he codes a thing to do it for him. And what is this glass pane? Also, the person (botter) has no access to the applet itself

Comment: *"And what is this glass pane?"*  And where is your initiative?  Add java to glass+pane in any search engine and you will likely see the top hit to the Oracle Java Tutorial.  Why don't you ask one of the 'botters' how they do it?  I'd guess the easiest way to hack the game would be to extend it then do pretty much what I put in the first comment.  *"the person (botter) has no access to the applet itself"*  I doubt that.  What is an example URL where we can see this happening?

Comment: I have asked a few, they don't know how to actually do it as they script for it. They have no idea how it works deep down. And yes they have access to the applet, what I meant was they had no direct access.

Answer (score -1):

Emm... quite strange question because you actually ask *how to create a game* or something :S

Drawing on 'layers' it is some kind of trivial Graphics2D + Swing task :)

You can use :

- A) [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)
- B) Use [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) as a layer
- C) Draw on your *JLabel layers* in [multithread](http://blue-walrus.com/?p=386) mode or something
  not to lose a background process...

So before writing that game or whatever you tried to concerning the layers effect you should better learn Java subjects like

- Graphics2D
- Swing/AWT
- Threads (Multithreading)

---

Report if that helped